# How high dimensional t-test in Feng's article has been obtained?

Tags: t-test, proof, high-dimensional

I'm reading [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279070596_A_note_on_high-dimensional_two-sample_test) and I am wondering how the authors obtained this test statistic!

[image]

I need to find out how they have done this!
Edit: in this article Mr. Feng just says that We propose this Statistic! And says nothing! I understand That this test has better performance in simulation and real data! But I need to know What is the main Idea of this test! Which calculation can leads to such test! thanks again.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what your specific question is, what do you understand? what don't you understand?

Comment: @JonathanLisic Thanks! In the article there isn't any points to Calculation method that leads to such test; I need something like a proof! thanks.